# JUnit - which step is executed now?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, debugging, junit

I use JUnit to run tests which have been designed for Cucumber and run on Firefox, but now they were transferred into work on Windows application.

When JUnit runs from eclipse, it marks every step which succeed or failed. I recognized that when it executes step #3 (for example), it marks that step #2 is currently executed. When the step is finished, it writes near step #2 how long it took. It confuses, but I can work with it.

But now I recognized a wonderful thing: I added `Sleep(60000)` to the code of the Windows application in the 3rd step. It causes the 2nd step (when it **actually** runs) to wait a minute! Although the 2nd step isn't supposed to know this `Sleep`!

I conclude that the JUnit runs the 3rd step together with the 2nd step, and this is the reason to this confusion.
Also, the result of #3 when JUnit in run mode is different from the result of #3 when in debug mode, for the same reason. In debug mode every step runs separately, so the result of #3 is what was expected. But in run mode it runs with the next step together and confuses itself.

Am I right in my conclusion? and how can I fix it? Is this a known bug?

Comment: You mean step #3 is marked as finished and step #2 is marked as "currently executed" when the execution reach the sleep in step #3? Could you provide an example as demonstration.

Comment: @SubOptimal No. I mean step #2 is marked as currently executed, and step #3 isn't marked, as other next steps which were not executed yet.
But actually the currently executed step is #3. When it finished, step #2 is marked as executed and 3rd step's duration is written near step #2.

Comment: Never had seen that. Could you provide a simple example which demonstrate this behavior? Which Eclipse, JUnit version are you using?